# Android fail to load google map in fragment

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to use google map in fragment, but I meet a problem I don't understand.

I don't arrive to load the map in this line :

```
gMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

This line seems to return always null...

I tried to use MapFragment inseatd of SupportMapFragment, but it's not possible.

How to resolve it ?

To explain why i want to show it in a fragment, it's because i'm using a navigationdrawer, and one of my item needs to show the map.

thx,

EDIT : My xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Comment: have your did all this Tutoiral : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Comment: yes, currently i'm using the google map in one of my activies, but i want to use it in one of my fragments, i changed just this line :/

Comment: please post xml layout.

Comment: your doing SupportMapFragment but inside the Xml your using MapFragment.. change it to com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Answer (score 1):

I think you should call with `getsupportFragmentManager` not with `getFragmentManager` otherwise it will return null always

Comment: just replace with getSupportfragmentmanager in place of getFragmentManager that's it. By the way can you show your xml code?

Comment: use this : class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment @deveLost

Answer (score 1):

#### If you are using **[SupportMapFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html)**, you need to change your layout!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

#### This is a basic example using **[SupportMapFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html)**:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    private SupportMapFragment map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
        map = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map.getMapAsync(this);//remember getMap() is deprecated!      
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
           map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(47.17, 27.5699), 16));      
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()               .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)).anchor(0.0f, 1.0f) // Anchors the marker on the bottom left
                    .position(new LatLng(47.17, 27.5699))); //Iasi, Romania
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);     
    }
}
```

and change the reference in your layout:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible as google map contains a < fragment> tag. See [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments) why:

> Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a . Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically.

Some people in SO however managed to show map in a fragment, but the solution was hacky.